# Regex not working - min 8 character, 1 Number, 1 special character and 1 uppercase letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression to check that checks for a minimum of 8 characters with 1 number, 1 special character and 1 uppercase letter.

```
function checkPassword(str) {
  var re = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})$/;
  return re.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Note that regular expressions have nothing to do with jQuery - they are pure JS. I changed the title and re-tagged the question for you

Comment: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,}$)/`

Comment: Since you have 4 explicit tests, why not just use 4 tests? `[/.{8,}/, /\d/, /[!@#\$%\^&\*]/, /[A-Z]/].every(re=>re.test(str))`.

Comment: You have only lookaheads chained between ^$ which requires zero length. Use something like `.{8,}$` instead of `(?=.{8,})$`

Comment: FYI, that's not a complete set of special characters. Something like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` may be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KISS - keep it simple.
Is your string length 8 or more? No? Test failed. Yes? Proceed.
Run 4 regex tests on string, one for each parameter.
4 truthy values means you're good to go. Any falsey values means no validation.
Complicated regex will always bite you with weird edge cases if you do not understand or test it thoroughly. Break it into smaller understandable pieces and run the tests consecutively. You want to be correct, not stylish.

Comment: Even better, by doing separate tests you can inform your user *which* test they failed.

Comment: ^ Yes. Ideally you validate live with each new char added and remove `disabled` from your submit button once all validation passes. It's more involved but it is also more user friendly.